# Which PowerApps license?

Tags: powerapps

We have around 40 office365 users with a seeded PowerApps license. from Office365.

Now, I need to develop an app that will consume data from Common Data Service, so my company needs to buy a "Per user" license.

My question is: when I share this app with the other users in the company, will they also need to buy additional licenses or can they just use their standard Office365 accounts? So, the scenario here is one developer, multiple users.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745).

Comment: Better place for this question is https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Forums/ct-p/PA_Comm_Forums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app depends on CDS, you will need PowerApps license in order to use the app. You can also consider the Per-app plan for your case, which allows individual users to run applications for a specific business scenario based on the full capabilities of PowerApps. Pricing will be $10 user/app/month. ([link to pricing details](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/?&ef_id=EAIaIQobChMIwZm0-bam5QIVEf5kCh2YuwcGEAAYASABEgKgt_D_BwE:G:s&OCID=AID2000569_SEM_GrNWQ89B&MarinID=sGrNWQ89B_358609764638_power%20apps%20licensing_e_c_qgyjj3OY_75418092947_aud-397602257972:kwd-967524826272_))